# ASP.NET MVC Bunding fails when i have async methods in my js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

We started moving our legacy js scripts to conform to the latest specification and changed a few js methods to async. For example

```
const persistMode = async (serverUrl, id, mode) => {
   const data = JSON.stringify({id: id, mode: mode});
   const ajaxProperties = {
       type: "POST",
       url: serverUrl,
       data: data,
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json"
   };
   return await $.ajax(ajaxProperties);
};
```

Now I have a bundle defined and referred it in the cshtml file as follows

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fc")
```

Now, when the view is loaded I am getting the following error

```
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseArrowFunction(AstNode parameters)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean&amp; isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpressionStatement(Boolean fSourceElement)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatement(Boolean fSourceElement, Boolean skipImportantComment)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatements(Block block)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.InternalParse()
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier.MinifyJavaScript(String source, CodeSettings codeSettings)
   at System.Web.Optimization.JsMinify.Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
   at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context, String bundleContent, IEnumerable`1 bundleFiles)
   at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GetBundleResponse(BundleContext context)
   at System.Web.Optimization.BundleResolver.GetBundleContents(String virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.DeterminePathsToRender(IEnumerable`1 assets)
   at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.RenderExplicit(String tagFormat, String[] paths)
   at ASP._Page_Views_xxx__xxxxxxxx_cshtml.Execute() in xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:line 479
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass3_1.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult);
```

Any idea what's wrong here. And, the bundling works if I remove the async/await from the said method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this algoritm :

```
function onSuccess(result) {

       ....succes code
    };

function onError(xhr, exceptio) {

       .... error code
    };

function getData( serverUrl, id, mode ) {

       var data={id: id, mode: mode}
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: serverUrl,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
              contentType: "application/json"
            success: function (result) {

                onSuccess(result);
               return true;
            },
            error: function (xhr, exception) {
                onError(xhr, exception);
                return false;
            }
        });
    };
```